# A primitive element in a field of order $r$ is a primitive $(r-1)$st root of unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

Could someone explain to me the following sentence?

"A primitive element in a field of order $r$ is a primitive $(r-1)$st root of unity."

Does this mean that for each element $x$ of a field of order $r$ it stands that $x^r-1=0$ and $x^n-1 \neq 0$ for $n<r$ ?

Comment: A primitive element in a finite field is one that generates the multiplicative subgroup (which is cyclic for any finite field). If $|F| = r$, then $|F^{\ast}| = r-1$, and thus a primitive element has (multiplicative) order $r-1$-that is, $x^{r-1} = 1$ and $x^n \neq 1$ for $0 \leq n < r-1$ (the standard definition of order in a group). Since we have a field, we can re-write these conditions as $x^{r-1} - 1 = 0$, while $x^n - 1 \neq 0$, for $0 \leq n < r-1$. So $x^r = x$ for all $x \in F$.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if $F$ is a field of order $r$ (that is, a field having exactly $r$ elements), and $x$ is a primitive element of $F$ (that is, every element of $F$ can be written as a power of $x$), then $x$ is a primitive $r-1$-st root of unity (that is, we have $x^{r-1} = 1$ but $x^n \neq 1$ for every $1 \leq n < r-1$).